# Thread.Sleep(0) not working as expected on .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

So, i'm studying the .NET Thread class based on the book: Exam Ref 70-483: Programming in C#, and i noticed something i don't know why it happens or if it should be happening.

The book give me this part of code on page 4:

```
public static class Program
{
   public static void ThreadMethod()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
           Thread.Sleep(0);
       }
   }
   public static void Main()
   {
       Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
       t.Start();
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
           Thread.Sleep(0);
       }
       t.Join();
   }
}
```

With the expected result showing below, since at each Thread.Sleep(0), the current thread exits and go to work on the next thread on the queue:

```
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 0  
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 1  
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 2  
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 3  
// ThreadProc: 4  
// ThreadProc: 5  
// ThreadProc: 6  
// ThreadProc: 7  
// ThreadProc: 8  
// ThreadProc: 9
```

But when i built my version of this, it didn't work as expected, even when i copy pasted the code and ran on my machine, it give this result every time a executed the program, **with the same code above**:

```
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 0  
// ThreadProc: 1  
// ThreadProc: 2  
// ThreadProc: 3  
// ThreadProc: 4  
// ThreadProc: 5  
// ThreadProc: 6  
// ThreadProc: 7  
// ThreadProc: 8  
// ThreadProc: 9  
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// Main thread: Do some work.
```

As you can see, it seems to enter the side thread and when i call Thread.Sleep(0) method it don't go back to the main thread as it should, and keeps working on the side thread until it finishes.

As an workaround for this, i used the Random class to generate a random number between 100 and 500 to pass to the Thread.Sleep() method, and it starts to work as expected:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void ThreadMethod()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(100, 500));
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        t.Start();
        var rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
            Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(100, 500));
        }
        t.Join();
    }
}
```

With the results looking like this:

```
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 0  
// ThreadProc: 1  
// ThreadProc: 2  
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 3  
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 4  
// Main thread: Do some work.  
// ThreadProc: 5  
// ThreadProc: 6  
// ThreadProc: 7  
// ThreadProc: 8  
// ThreadProc: 9
```

I don't think the book was written on the .NET Core framework, and i thought this "problem" may be caused by the changes on the synchronization context between these two frameworks.
I checked the priority of the two threads and is set as the default "Normal".

Anyone have an idea of why this happens?

Comment: `and when i call Thread.Sleep(0) method it don't go back to the main thread as it should` Where do the docs say that it should?

Comment: @mjwills Well the documentation does state that `Thread.Sleep(0)` yields to another thread that is ready to run, so it can be confusing. The trick is that there is no thread in ready-to-run state in this example, since both threads are scheduled on their own core and don't have to compete for resources

Comment: So is that what `If there are no other threads of equal priority that are ready to run, execution of the current thread is not suspended.` means @KevinGosse?

Comment: @mjwills Yep. `Thread.Sleep(0)` means "check if another thread is waiting to run. If so, let it run instead. If not, keep running". This was pretty useful when CPUs had a single core, nowadays it's used only in spin-lock primitives I believe

Comment: Awesome - that is why I asked the question of the OP. Since the docs don't _actually_ state what he/she said they stated.

Comment: For a more straightforward, semantically consistent and no-surprises way to yield the execution to another thread, see [`Thread.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.yield).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't see any difference of behavior between .net framework and .net core for this example.

The book was written at an era where most consumer CPUs were single core. With a single core CPU, only one thread can be scheduled at a time, and therefore the output of the sample is predictable.

Nowadays, pretty much all CPUs have multiple cores, meaning that multiple threads can be scheduled at the same time. This makes the output of the program unpredictable, and unaffected by the calls to `Thread.Sleep(0)`.

One way to get the behavior described on the book on modern hardware is to set the affinity of your process so that it runs on a single core:

```
> start /affinity 1 CoreConsoleApp1.exe
```

By doing that, I get the expected interleaved output:

```
ThreadProc: 0
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 1
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 2
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 3
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 4
ThreadProc: 5
ThreadProc: 6
ThreadProc: 7
ThreadProc: 8
ThreadProc: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect definite behavior with threads. If you are going for synchronization, don't use the sleep function.

Try to change the main loop to 10000 loops and do the same with the thread loop.

You'll see a much better and expected result. The fact that it can give the remaining time slice to another thread, does not mean that it won't be the new thread you are creating (instead of the main one)

That is, the .net framework decides the optimal way to schedule thread time and there are no guarantees. The `Thread.Sleep` function is there to just make sure that the other threads will sometime in the future be responsive.